# How to obtain the datetime index value at a specific row number

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, indexing

I am working with a dataframe that looks like this:

```
time                           value
2020-08-02 21:00:00+00:00        4  
2020-08-02 21:01:00+00:00        2
2020-08-02 21:02:00+00:00        3
2020-08-02 21:03:00+00:00        2  
2020-08-02 21:04:00+00:00        2
2020-08-02 21:05:00+00:00        3
2020-08-02 21:06:00+00:00        3
2020-08-02 21:07:00+00:00        3
2020-08-02 21:08:00+00:00        4
2020-08-02 21:09:00+00:00        4
2020-08-02 21:10:00+00:00        5
```

I would like to obtain datetime index value at row number 9 (i.e. at datetime " `2020-08-02 21:08:00+00:00` ")

when I use:

```
 print('Datetime at position 9 is %s' % df[df['value']==df.iat[9,0]].index[0])
```

I end up with:

```
Datetime at row 9 is 2020-08-02 21:00:00+00:00
```

and yet I expect:

```
Datetime at row 9 is 2020-08-02 21:08:00+00:00
```

I believe this is because the value '4' appears earlier in my df but that is not the datetime value that I am looking for. I am sure there is a quick fix to this but for some reason, I cant get my head round it.

(Searched through previous questions that all looked very similar but did not quite address this use case.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
print('Datetime at position 9 is %s' % df.index[9])
```

credit to Noah - thanks for your detailed explanation - it got me thinking

Answer (score 1):

Just keep it simple :)

```
print('Datetime at position 9 is %s' % df.iat[9,0])
```

You are probably better off with getting the column name dynamically when possible:

```
df.iat[9, df.columns.get_loc("time")]
```

***Why*** your solution failed:

```
df[df['value']==df.iat[9,0]].index[0]
```

Let's break it down:

`df[...].index[0]` will take whatever `df[...]` returns, get the index, and return the 0th element of that index.

`df['value']==df.iat[9,0]` will give you the df for all values equal to whatever is at position `9,0`. You now have the following df:

```
time                           value
2020-08-02 21:00:00+00:00        4  
2020-08-02 21:08:00+00:00        4
2020-08-02 21:09:00+00:00        4
```

The index of the dataframe is set to be time so the `.index` gives us the times:

```
time
2020-08-02 21:00:00+00:00 
2020-08-02 21:08:00+00:00
2020-08-02 21:09:00+00:00
```

Now we get the 0th element: `2020-08-02 21:00:00+00:00`

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. For some reason using "df.iat[9,0]" gives me the actual value at the location (i.e. "4") and yet I am after the date time index value